# как поменять цвет фона на данном примере?

Tags: javascript, canvas

```js
'use strict';
Math.TAU = Math.PI * 2;

Math.RAD = Math.PI / 180;

Math.DEG = 180 / Math.PI;

Math.PHI = 0.5 + 0.5 * Math.sqrt(5);

Math.random = (function(x) {
    return function() {
        x ^= x << 13;
        x ^= x >>> 17;
        x ^= x << 5;
        return 1 - (x >>> 0) / 0xFFFFFFFF;
    };
})(1);

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    

        var _, buffer, canvas, colors, context, data, j, k, l, model, mvp, palette, points, projection, render, v, view,
            x, y, z, zero, θ, ρ, φ;
        canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        // document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        buffer = mat4.create();
        model = mat4.create();
        view = mat4.create();
        projection = mat4.create();
        mvp = mat4.create();
        points = [];
        colors = [];
        palette = [[1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 0.30], [0.25, 0.50, 1.00, 0.75]].map(vec4.clone);


        for (_ = j = 0; j < 25000; _ = ++j) {
            ρ = 3 / 5;
            θ = Math.acos(Math.random() * 2 - 1);
            φ = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
            x = ρ * Math.sin(θ) * Math.cos(φ);
            y = ρ * Math.sin(θ) * Math.sin(φ);
            z = ρ * Math.cos(θ);
            points.push(v = vec4.fromValues(x, y, z, 1));
            colors.push(palette[0]);
        }
        for (_ = k = 0; k < 25000; _ = ++k) {
            x = (1 - Math.pow(Math.random(), 5)) * ((Math.random() * 2 << 1) - 1);
            y = (1 - Math.pow(Math.random(), 5)) * ((Math.random() * 2 << 1) - 1);
            z = (1 - Math.pow(Math.random(), 5)) * ((Math.random() * 2 << 1) - 1);
            points.push(v = vec4.fromValues(x, y, z, 1));
            colors.push(palette[1]);
        }
        for (_ = l = 0; l < 50000; _ = ++l) {
            x = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
            y = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
            z = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
            points.push(v = vec4.fromValues(x, y, z, 1));
            colors.push(palette[ρ < vec3.len(v) ? 1 : 0]);
        }
        data = null;
        zero = null;
        return (render = function () {
            var H, T, W, a, b, g, i, len, m, n, point, r, ref, ref1, w;
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
            T = 1e-3 * Date.now();
            W = canvas.clientWidth;
            H = canvas.clientHeight;
            if (W !== canvas.width || H !== canvas.height) {
                canvas.width = W;
                canvas.height = H;
                data = context.createImageData(W, H);
                zero = context.createImageData(W, H);


                for (i = m = 3, ref = zero.data.length; m < ref; i = m += 4) {
                    zero.data[i] = 0xFF;
                }
                data.data.set(zero.data);
            }
            mat4.identity(model);
            mat4.rotateX(model, model, T / 5);
            mat4.rotateY(model, model, T / 6);
            mat4.rotateZ(model, model, T / 7);
            mat4.lookAt(view, [0, 0, 5], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]);
            mat4.perspective(projection, 30 * Math.RAD, W / H, 1e-3, 1e3);
            [model, view, projection].reduce(function (a, b) {
                return mat4.mul(mvp, b, a);
            });
            for (i = n = 0, len = points.length; n < len; i = ++n) {
                point = points[i];
                vec4.transformMat4(buffer, point, mvp);
                vec3.scale(buffer, buffer, 1 / buffer[3]);
                x = buffer[0], y = buffer[1], z = buffer[2], w = buffer[3];
                if ((-1 < z && z < 1) && (-1 < y && y < 1) && (-1 < x && x < 1)) {
                    ref1 = colors[i], r = ref1[0], g = ref1[1], b = ref1[2], a = ref1[3];
                    x = (1 + x) * 0.5 * W | 0;
                    y = (1 - y) * 0.5 * H | 0;
                    i = x + y * W << 2;
                    a = a * H / w;
                    data.data[i++] += r * a;
                    data.data[i++] += g * a;
                    data.data[i++] += b * a;
                }
            }


            context.putImageData(data, 0, 0);
            return data.data.set(zero.data);

        })();


    

});
```

```css
html {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  background: #1A1D3E;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 720px;
  background: #1A1D3E;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.3.1/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот тот участок кода, который я поменял:

```
for (i = 0; i < zero.data.length; i += 4) {
    zero.data[i] = 0x11;   // r
    zero.data[i+1] = 0x44; // g
    zero.data[i+2] = 0x11; // b
    zero.data[i+3] = 0xff;
}
```

```js
'use strict';
Math.TAU = Math.PI * 2;

Math.RAD = Math.PI / 180;

Math.DEG = 180 / Math.PI;

Math.PHI = 0.5 + 0.5 * Math.sqrt(5);

Math.random = (function(x) {
    return function() {
        x ^= x << 13;
        x ^= x >>> 17;
        x ^= x << 5;
        return 1 - (x >>> 0) / 0xFFFFFFFF;
    };
})(1);

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    

        var _, buffer, canvas, colors, context, data, j, k, l, model, mvp, palette, points, projection, render, v, view,
            x, y, z, zero, θ, ρ, φ;
        canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        // document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        buffer = mat4.create();
        model = mat4.create();
        view = mat4.create();
        projection = mat4.create();
        mvp = mat4.create();
        points = [];
        colors = [];
        palette = [[1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 0.30], [0.25, 0.50, 1.00, 0.75]].map(vec4.clone);


        for (_ = j = 0; j < 25000; _ = ++j) {
            ρ = 3 / 5;
            θ = Math.acos(Math.random() * 2 - 1);
            φ = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
            x = ρ * Math.sin(θ) * Math.cos(φ);
            y = ρ * Math.sin(θ) * Math.sin(φ);
            z = ρ * Math.cos(θ);
            points.push(v = vec4.fromValues(x, y, z, 1));
            colors.push(palette[0]);
        }
        for (_ = k = 0; k < 25000; _ = ++k) {
            x = (1 - Math.pow(Math.random(), 5)) * ((Math.random() * 2 << 1) - 1);
            y = (1 - Math.pow(Math.random(), 5)) * ((Math.random() * 2 << 1) - 1);
            z = (1 - Math.pow(Math.random(), 5)) * ((Math.random() * 2 << 1) - 1);
            points.push(v = vec4.fromValues(x, y, z, 1));
            colors.push(palette[1]);
        }
        for (_ = l = 0; l < 50000; _ = ++l) {
            x = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
            y = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
            z = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
            points.push(v = vec4.fromValues(x, y, z, 1));
            colors.push(palette[ρ < vec3.len(v) ? 1 : 0]);
        }
        data = null;
        zero = null;
        return (render = function () {
            var H, T, W, a, b, g, i, len, m, n, point, r, ref, ref1, w;
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
            T = 1e-3 * Date.now();
            W = canvas.clientWidth;
            H = canvas.clientHeight;
            if (W !== canvas.width || H !== canvas.height) {
                canvas.width = W;
                canvas.height = H;
                data = context.createImageData(W, H);
                zero = context.createImageData(W, H);
                for (i = 0; i < zero.data.length; i += 4) {
                    zero.data[i] = 0x11;   // r
                    zero.data[i+1] = 0x44; // g
                    zero.data[i+2] = 0x11; // b
                    zero.data[i+3] = 0xff;
                }
                data.data.set(zero.data);
            }
            mat4.identity(model);
            mat4.rotateX(model, model, T / 5);
            mat4.rotateY(model, model, T / 6);
            mat4.rotateZ(model, model, T / 7);
            mat4.lookAt(view, [0, 0, 5], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]);
            mat4.perspective(projection, 30 * Math.RAD, W / H, 1e-3, 1e3);
            [model, view, projection].reduce(function (a, b) {
                return mat4.mul(mvp, b, a);
            });
            for (i = n = 0, len = points.length; n < len; i = ++n) {
                point = points[i];
                vec4.transformMat4(buffer, point, mvp);
                vec3.scale(buffer, buffer, 1 / buffer[3]);
                x = buffer[0], y = buffer[1], z = buffer[2], w = buffer[3];
                if ((-1 < z && z < 1) && (-1 < y && y < 1) && (-1 < x && x < 1)) {
                    ref1 = colors[i], r = ref1[0], g = ref1[1], b = ref1[2], a = ref1[3];
                    x = (1 + x) * 0.5 * W | 0;
                    y = (1 - y) * 0.5 * H | 0;
                    i = x + y * W << 2;
                    a = a * H / w;
                    data.data[i++] += r * a;
                    data.data[i++] += g * a;
                    data.data[i++] += b * a;
                }
            }


            context.putImageData(data, 0, 0);
            return data.data.set(zero.data);

        })();


    

});
```

```css
html {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;

}

canvas {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 720px;

}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.3.1/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

нужно поменять 
 `palette = [[2.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.0], [0.25, 5, 1.00, 0.75]]`
первый элемент массива - круг, второй - квадрат(RGB)

```js
'use strict';
Math.TAU = Math.PI * 2;

Math.RAD = Math.PI / 180;

Math.DEG = 180 / Math.PI;

Math.PHI = 0.5 + 0.5 * Math.sqrt(5);

Math.random = (function(x) {
    return function() {
        x ^= x << 13;
        x ^= x >>> 17;
        x ^= x << 5;
        return 1 - (x >>> 0) / 0xFFFFFFFF;
    };
})(1);

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    

        var _, buffer, canvas, colors, context, data, j, k, l, model, mvp, palette, points, projection, render, v, view,
            x, y, z, zero, θ, ρ, φ;
        canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        // document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        buffer = mat4.create();
        model = mat4.create();
        view = mat4.create();
        projection = mat4.create();
        mvp = mat4.create();
        points = [];
        colors = [];
        palette = [[2.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.0], [0.25, 5, 1.00, 0.75]].map(vec4.clone);


        for (_ = j = 0; j < 25000; _ = ++j) {
            ρ = 3 / 5;
            θ = Math.acos(Math.random() * 2 - 1);
            φ = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
            x = ρ * Math.sin(θ) * Math.cos(φ);
            y = ρ * Math.sin(θ) * Math.sin(φ);
            z = ρ * Math.cos(θ);
            points.push(v = vec4.fromValues(x, y, z, 1));
            colors.push(palette[0]);
        }
        for (_ = k = 0; k < 25000; _ = ++k) {
            x = (1 - Math.pow(Math.random(), 5)) * ((Math.random() * 2 << 1) - 1);
            y = (1 - Math.pow(Math.random(), 5)) * ((Math.random() * 2 << 1) - 1);
            z = (1 - Math.pow(Math.random(), 5)) * ((Math.random() * 2 << 1) - 1);
            points.push(v = vec4.fromValues(x, y, z, 1));
            colors.push(palette[1]);
        }
        for (_ = l = 0; l < 50000; _ = ++l) {
            x = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
            y = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
            z = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
            points.push(v = vec4.fromValues(x, y, z, 1));
            colors.push(palette[ρ < vec3.len(v) ? 1 : 0]);
        }
        data = null;
        zero = null;
        return (render = function () {
            var H, T, W, a, b, g, i, len, m, n, point, r, ref, ref1, w;
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
            T = 1e-3 * Date.now();
            W = canvas.clientWidth;
            H = canvas.clientHeight;
            if (W !== canvas.width || H !== canvas.height) {
                canvas.width = W;
                canvas.height = H;
                data = context.createImageData(W, H);
                zero = context.createImageData(W, H);


                for (i = m = 3, ref = zero.data.length; m < ref; i = m += 4) {
                    zero.data[i] = 0xFF;
                }
                data.data.set(zero.data);
            }
            mat4.identity(model);
            mat4.rotateX(model, model, T / 5);
            mat4.rotateY(model, model, T / 6);
            mat4.rotateZ(model, model, T / 7);
            mat4.lookAt(view, [0, 0, 5], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]);
            mat4.perspective(projection, 30 * Math.RAD, W / H, 1e-3, 1e3);
            [model, view, projection].reduce(function (a, b) {
                return mat4.mul(mvp, b, a);
            });
            for (i = n = 0, len = points.length; n < len; i = ++n) {
                point = points[i];
                vec4.transformMat4(buffer, point, mvp);
                vec3.scale(buffer, buffer, 1 / buffer[3]);
                x = buffer[0], y = buffer[1], z = buffer[2], w = buffer[3];
                if ((-1 < z && z < 1) && (-1 < y && y < 1) && (-1 < x && x < 1)) {
                    ref1 = colors[i], r = ref1[0], g = ref1[1], b = ref1[2], a = ref1[3];
                    x = (1 + x) * 0.5 * W | 0;
                    y = (1 - y) * 0.5 * H | 0;
                    i = x + y * W << 2;
                    a = a * H / w;
                    data.data[i++] += r * a;
                    data.data[i++] += g * a;
                    data.data[i++] += b * a;
                }
            }


            context.putImageData(data, 0, 0);
            return data.data.set(zero.data);

        })();


    

});
```

```css
html {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  background: #1A1D3E;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 720px;
  background: #1A1D3E;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.3.1/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
```